# FFTW.NET DFT.FFT(pinIn, pinOut) is throwing System.InvalidOperationException in WEB API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1, fftw, .net-core-2.1

I want to use FFTW.NET in .NET Core 2.1 WEB API. When I execute below piece of code in action, I get `System.InvalidOperationException: 'IsAvailable returns false.'` at `DFT.FFT(pinIn, pinOut);`

```
        Complex[] input = new Complex[1024];
        Complex[] output = new Complex[input.Length];

        //Initialize input         

        using (var pinIn = new PinnedArray<Complex>(input))
        using (var pinOut = new PinnedArray<Complex>(output))
        {
            DFT.FFT(pinIn, pinOut);
        }
```

Below is the stacktrace.

```
   at FFTW.NET.FftwPlan`2..ctor(IPinnedArray`1 buffer1, IPinnedArray`1 buffer2, Int32 rank, Int32[] n, Boolean verifyRankAndSize, DftDirection direction, PlannerFlags plannerFlags, Int32 nThreads)
   at FFTW.NET.FftwPlanC2C.Create(IPinnedArray`1 input, IPinnedArray`1 output, DftDirection direction, PlannerFlags plannerFlags, Int32 nThreads)
   at FFTW.NET.DFT.Transform(IPinnedArray`1 input, IPinnedArray`1 output, DftDirection direction, PlannerFlags plannerFlags, Int32 nThreads)
   at FFTW.NET.DFT.FFT(IPinnedArray`1 input, IPinnedArray`1 output, PlannerFlags plannerFlags, Int32 nThreads)
   at FFTW_WEB_API.Controllers.ValuesController.Get() in D:\FFTW_Test\FFTW_WEB_API\Controllers\ValuesController.cs:line 1059
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
```

But the same piece of code works fine in .NET Core 2.1 Console Application.

Please suggest if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IsAvailable` is called internally to test whether the interop layer is happy - [found here](https://github.com/ArgusMagnus/FFTW.NET/blob/master/FFTW.NET/FftwInterop.cs).

It looks like it'll return `false` if trying to load the Dll resulted in a `DllNotFoundException` (via the `GetVersionAndInitialize` and `_version`).

So the native DLLs aren't in the right place to be loaded. If it's not clear which locations are being probed for the DLLs you might want to use [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to look for the failed probing attempts to load the DLLs.